# how to remove underline on link?

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem in  
each   which I either picture or word, appear ......... below

I already gave css external event internal like this

```
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;  
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

that problem appear in safari10,mozilla 8, and google chrome

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: Have a look in chrome's inspector to see if there's a more specific style taking priority like `.mydiv a{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;  
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

I believe that they need to be in this order.

*PLEASE READ THE COMMENTS. THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION*

Comment: http://www.quackit.com/css/css_hyperlinks.cfm

Note that the a:hover must be placed after the a:link and a:visited rules, since otherwise the cascading rules will hide the effect of the a:hover rule. Similarly, because a:active is placed after a:hover, the active color will apply when the user both activates and hovers over the 'anchor' element.

Comment: Either way, don't think my answer should have been voted down without looking up the information first. I would assume, that since I found many sites saying the same thing, that the rule order has to make some difference.

Comment: And here too: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Note: a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS definition in order to be effective!!

Note: a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order to be effective!!

Comment: Nice way to build a community. Two votes down for my answer, when I was the first one that gave a proper answer. The all-in-one solution may work, but doesn't answer the question of WHY it wasn't working in the first place. It wasn't working because the order of the rules was wrong.

Comment: I know when I post questions sometimes I make them simpler so that they are easier to understand. I believe the original question was why those four rules, when put in that order, didn't work. The reason is because the order is wrong, according to official documentation. The all-in-one shortcut is just that, a shortcut, but it doesn't answer the question of how to apply the four separate rules individually. So while it may not matter when they are all the same not everyone that will read this page will be in the same case, and they may want to know the CORRECT way to apply these rules.

Comment: Voted up for fairness: the answerer obviously made some researches and provided evidence. @SherwinFlight don't blame the community, blame the people.

Comment: And another: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

When setting the style for several link states, there are some order rules:

    a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited
    a:active MUST come after a:hover

And they put MUST in capital letters, not me.

Comment: w3schools is an authority on nothing, and honestly - OP's code already works if you actually test it.

Comment: I have run into this same problem before as well. There's a reason that W3C says "MUST". I'm sure they didn't just make it up for fun. I'm sure some browsers may interpret it correctly, however not all will. If they say to do it a certain way, and the original poster did it differently and it didn't work, there's a reason why.

Answer (score 11):

Did you try this?

```
a {
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: This is a shortcut for achieving the same results. My answer has the correct way of applying the rules separately the way the original poster asked. So if anyone is having the same problem, but needs different styles for each rule, my answer shows the correct way to do it.

Comment: I would say that your answer is just correct if the user wants to achieve compleatly different results on the pseudo classes. But I think that a base style like in my answer is a better practice. So the user has just to define the difference to the base style. Which must be in your order.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily remove the underline using the CSS property `text-decoration` just set it to `none` for the different states of the link.

**Example:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            a:link {text-decoration: none;}    /* unvisited link */
            a:visited {text-decoration: none;} /* visited link */
            a:hover {text-decoration: none;}   /* mouse over link */
            a:active {text-decoration: none;}  /* selected link */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link without underline</a>
    </body>
</html>
```